# How to include correlated subquery clause in SQL Join?

Tags: sql, db2, subquery, syntax-error, correlated-subquery

So I'm trying to write a query that includes an IN clause within a join. The reason is because I need to join DLGVRSN to itself, and when the first one's `DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 500` then I need it to get the most-recent version of the second one that's been updated before the first DLGVRSN's date.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CCCX.DLGVRSN
    LEFT JOIN CCCX.QSTVRSN
        ON QSTVRSN.DVFK = DLGVRSN.DID
    LEFT JOIN CCCX.DLGVRSN SQS_DLGVRSN
        ON SQS_DLGVRSN.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK
        AND (
            (
                DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 500
                AND SQS_DLGVRSN.DID IN ( -- Error occurs on this line.
                    SELECT DID
                    FROM CCCX.DLGVRSN LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE
                    WHERE
                        LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK
                        AND LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DATEUPD <= IFNULL(DLGVRSN.DATEUPD, DLGVRSN.DATECRT)
                    ORDER BY DATEUPD DESC
                    FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
                )
            ) OR (
                DLGVRSN.DSTATUS <> 500
                AND SQS_DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 100
            )
        )
WHERE
    DLGVRSN.DID = 32367
```

However, it complains:

> [SQL0115] Comparison operator IN not valid. Cause . . . . . :   Simple comparison operators other than equal and not equal cannot be used with a list of items.  ANY, ALL, and SOME comparison operators must be followed by a fullselect, rather than an expression or a list of items. Subqueries cannot be specified in a JOIN condition or in a CASE expression. Recovery  . . . :   Change either the comparison or the operand.  Try the request again.

Looking at other Questions on here, it was suggested that I change it to use a separate join, instead.
So I tried changing it to this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CCCX.DLGVRSN
    LEFT JOIN CCCX.QSTVRSN
        ON QSTVRSN.DVFK = DLGVRSN.DID
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DID
            , LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DHFK
        FROM CCCX.DLGVRSN LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE
        WHERE
            LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK -- Error occurs on this line.
            AND LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DATEUPD <= IFNULL(DLGVRSN.DATEUPD, DLGVRSN.DATECRT)
        ORDER BY DATEUPD DESC
        FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ) HISTORIC_MODEL_SQS_IDS
        ON HISTORIC_MODEL_SQS_IDS.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK 
    LEFT JOIN CCCX.DLGVRSN SQS_DLGVRSN
        ON SQS_DLGVRSN.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK
        AND (
            (
                DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 500
                AND SQS_DLGVRSN.DID = HISTORIC_MODEL_SQS_IDS.DID
            ) OR (
                DLGVRSN.DSTATUS <> 500
                AND SQS_DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 100
            )
        )
WHERE
    DLGVRSN.DID = 32367
```

But when I do that, it complains about not finding DLGVRSN nor QSTVRSN:

> [SQL0206] Column or global variable DSUBFK not found. Cause . . . . . :   DSUBFK was not found as a column of table *N in *N and was not found as a global variable in *N. If the table is *N, DSUBFK is not a column of any table or view that can be referenced, or DSUBFK is a special register that cannot be set in an atomic compound statement. Recovery  . . . :   Do one of the following and try the request again: -- Ensure that the column and table names are specified correctly in the statement. -- If this is a SELECT statement, ensure that all the required tables were named in the FROM clause. -- If the column was intended to be a correlated reference, qualify the column with the correct table designator. -- If the column was intended to be a global variable, qualify the name with the schema where the global variable exists or ensure the schema is in the path. -- If this is a SET statement for a special register within an atomic compound dynamic statement, remove the statement or remove the ATOMIC keyword.

I likewise tried to change the subquery to use MAX(DID) so I could use `=` instead of `IN`. That gives the same error as the second example above.

So... how can I accomplish this?

Relevant DDL:

```
CREATE TABLE CCCX/DLGVRSN ( 
    DID DECIMAL(11, 0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
    MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE 
    NO CYCLE ORDER 
    CACHE 20 ) 
    , 
    DSTATUS NUMERIC(3, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
    DHFK DECIMAL(11, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
    DATECRT TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , 
    DATEUPD TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL , 
    CONSTRAINT CCCX/Q_DLGVRSN_DID_00001 PRIMARY KEY( DID ) )   
      
    RCDFMT CC0102P    ;
  

CREATE TABLE CCCX/QSTVRSN ( 
    QID DECIMAL(11, 0) GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( 
    START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 
    MINVALUE 1 NO MAXVALUE 
    NO CYCLE ORDER 
    CACHE 20 ) 
    ,
    DVFK DECIMAL(11, 0) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 , 
    DSUBFK DECIMAL(11, 0) DEFAULT NULL , 
    CONSTRAINT CCCX/Q_QUESTION_QID_00001 PRIMARY KEY( QID ) )   
      
    RCDFMT CC0108P    ;
  
ALTER TABLE CCCX/QSTVRSN 
    ADD CONSTRAINT CCCX/Q_QSTVRSN_DVFK_00001 
    FOREIGN KEY( DVFK ) 
    REFERENCES CCCX/DLGVRSN ( DID ) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION ;
```

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either  with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & ideally a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: @philipxy ...? I don't understand. "why you think it should return something else" - because it gives an error instead of returning values. I included both the SQL and the error in my Question. I want it to not throw an error.

Comment: By "return something else" I include returning an error message. B anyway I immediately say "or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect". Please act on the comment. PS "accomplish this" You don't say or give an example of what you want to accomplish. You just give fragments of code not accomplishing it.

Comment: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read manuals/references & google error messages & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help] Reflect research in posts.

Comment: @philipxy Sorry, I still don't understand what you mean. Because it's a correlated subquery (that is, it references tables in the outer query), I'm unable to run the subexpression on its own. So it can't return anything if I run it on its own outside of the larger query, and if I run it inside as-is inside the larger query, then it throws the error.

Comment: Again: Please give a [mre] re 1 problem query.

Comment: I'm not sure what isn't an MRE about this. I removed everything irrelevant from the query, and there's only the one syntax error in each.

Did you want me to write an actual program or something? I don't think that's possible since it wouldn't run without access to the database.

Comment: A [mre] includes cut & paste & runnable code including initialization; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For SQL include DDL & tabular initialization code. For debug that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. [ask] [Help] When you get a result you don't expect, pause your overall goal, chop to the 1st subexpression with unexpected result & say what you expected & why, justified by documentation. (Debugging fundamental.) I'm done.

Comment: @philipxy Oh, I see. I'll add DDL then. Tangent - I didn't see anything about DDL in the MRE link you gave. If that's necessary, shouldn't the page be updated to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you code a subquery that refers to a column of an other table of the from clause, you have to use the `LATERAL` keyword to make it available inside the subquery

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    CCCX.DLGVRSN
    LEFT JOIN CCCX.QSTVRSN
        ON QSTVRSN.DVFK = DLGVRSN.DID
    LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
        SELECT
            LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DID
            , LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DHFK
        FROM CCCX.DLGVRSN LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE
        WHERE
            LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK -- Error occurs on this line.
            AND LATEST_SQS_BEFORE_DATE.DATEUPD <= IFNULL(DLGVRSN.DATEUPD, DLGVRSN.DATECRT)
        ORDER BY DATEUPD DESC
        FETCH FIRST ROW ONLY
    ) HISTORIC_MODEL_SQS_IDS
        ON HISTORIC_MODEL_SQS_IDS.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK 
    LEFT JOIN CCCX.DLGVRSN SQS_DLGVRSN
        ON SQS_DLGVRSN.DHFK = QSTVRSN.DSUBFK
        AND (
            (
                DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 500
                AND SQS_DLGVRSN.DID = HISTORIC_MODEL_SQS_IDS.DID
            ) OR (
                DLGVRSN.DSTATUS <> 500
                AND SQS_DLGVRSN.DSTATUS = 100
            )
        )
WHERE
    DLGVRSN.DID = 32367
```

Comment: Had no idea that existed, but it's exactly what I need. Thanks!